# What is the story behind Nene Sakurada's rabbit coming to life in Crayon Shin Chan?

Tags: crayon-shin-chan

I'm watching the Funimation dub of Shin Chan, and have come across the various episodes about "Happiness Bunny's Revenge", where Nene / Penny's rabbit doll comes alive whenever the moon is red.

The episodes always give me the creeps and seem really out of place for a children's TV show, as it often depicts the rabbit with glowing red eyes chasing after Nene / Penny or just being unpleasant towards the other characters.

I suspect these are nightmares she's having as a result of feeling bad about hitting the rabbit when she's angry, but some more info about the original Japanese story / stories would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Nene Sakurada and her mother received this mysterious bunny from a sweatshop by a little boy. The story says the bunny comes to life during the red moon night and seeks revenge for the pain and abuse the Sakuradas caused him, this mysterious character has red eyes and a creepy face. In one of the episodes, it had a conversation with Shiro, Shinchan's dog.

Comment: Is that the story in the original Japanese anime, or is that the plot from the Funimation dub? Because the episode "Get Your Hands Off My Happy Cake" shows Penny (Nene) buying the bunny from a store and the bunny telling the story of a child with bleeding hands sewing his plastic nose and lamenting how life was unfair